# I always get the same result for sf

Tags: java, math, methods

```
    public void berechne2() {
        float sf=16_777_220f;
        System.out.println("sf vorher = " + sf);
        int n=100;
        int d=1;
        for(int k=1; k<=n;k++) {
            sf=sf+d;
        }
        System.out.println("sf nachher = " + sf);
    }
```

}

Why do i get always same values for sf? I want to get sf+ the numbers from 1 to 100.

Comment: Use double instead of float. Float doesn't have enough precision to represent all these numbers.

Comment: sorry, i want to add the numbers from 1 to 100 on sf and print it just once

Comment: @Eran i dont get a overflow. i get always identical numbers
I have the problem in berechne2()

Comment: It's not a matter of overflow. It's a matter of precision.  Try, for example, `float sf=16_777_220f; float sf1=16_777_221f; System.out.println (sf==sf1);`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you need a float.

Your code can  be greatly simplified to

```
int sf=16_777_220;
System.out.println("sf vorher = " + sf);
for(int k=1; k<=100;k++) {
     System.out.println("sf nachher = " + sf++);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm wondering why you want to use a floating point variable in order to sum up integers… You could use an `int` or a `long` instead.

You commented *i want to add the numbers from 1 to 100 on sf and print it just once*, but that is not what your code is doing. It adds 1 to `sf` in each iteration to the initial value instead of adding 1 + 2 + ... + 100, the numbers from 1 to 100.

You are getting *equality* due to `float` as data type as mentioned in a comment. If you used a `double`, it would produce different values but would still appear pointless for integer values.

Maybe try something like this:

```java
public static void berechne2() {
    // use a data type meant for integers
    long sf = 16_777_220L;
    // print the initial value
    System.out.println("sf vorher  = " + sf);
    // use values in the loop instead of variables
    for (int k = 1; k <= 100; k++) {
        // add the current value of k to the variable, not just 1
        sf += k;
    }
    // print the result once
    System.out.println("sf nachher = " + sf);
}
```

Output:

```
sf vorher  = 16777220
sf nachher = 16782270
```